# function continuous at a limit point (Rudin) theorem question

Tags: real-analysis, continuity

in Rudin, we are given in Theorem 4.6:

"assume p is a limit point of E. Then f is continuous at p if and only if

$ \lim_{x \to p}$$ f(x) = f(p)$"

What if p is an isolated point of E? does this if and only if still hold?

Well, all functions are continuous at isolated points, so the (<==) direction must certainly hold. Since for any point $p$, and for any $\epsilon$, we can choose $\delta$ small enough to just include the $ p $. which has a distance to itself of zero, and 0 < $\epsilon$.

does the (==>) direction hold as well?
I'm  pretty sure it does. Since if we employ the definition of a limit, we can use the same vacuous argument, isolating just the point p, to make $\epsilon = 0$.

what do you guys think?

Answer (score 0):

For isolated point $p$ both statements are true and hence, the implications are valid.

Edit: The above answer is wrong. Rudin does only define the limit of functions for limit point (p. 83). Therefore, one of the statements is not defined.

Comment: did I give appropriate reasoning for the forward direction, in the case that $p$ was an isolated point?

Comment: You don't need to show any direction. You can just prove that both statements are true if the point is isolated.

Comment: I am sorry, I did not check the definitions of Rudin till now.

Comment: thank you for coming back and clarifying that. I really appreciate it